# TSQL Row Level Security Predicate Table Function Logic (IF/ELSE)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to create a `Row Level Security Function` which returns access if the current logged in user is a `ReportUser`.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[userIdPredicate](@siteId AS INT)
    RETURNS TABLE
    WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    IF (SUSER_SNAME() = 'ReportUser')
    BEGIN
        RETURN SELECT 1 AS accessResult
    END

    RETURN SELECT 1 AS accessResult 
           FROM dbo.UserGroup
           JOIN dbo.[Group] ON [Group].Id = UserGroup.GroupId
           JOIN dbo.SiteGroup ON SiteGroup.GroupId = [Group].Id
           JOIN dbo.Site ON Site.Id = SiteGroup.SiteId
           WHERE ApplicationUserId = CAST(SESSION_CONTEXT(N'UserId') AS NVARCHAR(450))
             AND dbo.SITE.Id = @siteId
END
```

Currently the predicate works fine without the `IF statement` but when I include the IF statement I get the error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 31, Procedure userIdPredicate, Line 21
>   Incorrect syntax near 'BEGIN'.

Is what I am trying to do possible and if so, can anyone suggest a solution please?

Comment: you are trying to create an inline function, which requires a single `select` query. Hence the error. you dont even need a table valued function, just a scalar function will do based on your requirement

Comment: Why not use the appropriate security layer for this?

Comment: All the examples I have found use a table function to achieve row level security, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669076(v=vs.110).aspx for example

Comment: What is the appropriate security layer, can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate IFs with ORs. You can put different query in every particular OR thus simulating IFs. Here is an example for access filtering :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [rls].[subcodeAccessPredicate](@SubcodeId int)
    RETURNS TABLE
    WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS 
    RETURN
    (
          SELECT 1 AS fn_securitypredicate_result FROM [dbo].[DataAccesses]
            -- if the companyUser has direct subcode access
            WHERE SubcodeId = @SubcodeId AND CompanyUserId = SESSION_CONTEXT(N'CompanyUserId') 
            -- if a group in thich the companyUser is has direct subcode access
            OR SubcodeId = @SubcodeId AND UserGroupId IN (SELECT UserGroup_Id FROM CompanyUserUserGroups WHERE CompanyUser_Id = SESSION_CONTEXT(N'CompanyUserId'))
            -- if wathever
            OR EXISTS (SELECT Id FROM somewhere WHERE somewhere.Id = 1 OR 2)
            -- else give every row because this is not filtered
            OR SESSION_CONTEXT(N'filteredForUser') = 0 
    )
GO
```